# Why is my start variable being changed before this for loop runs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, for-loop

So the strangest thing is happening.

I have this node.js express server that I want to run a function when it starts.

When it starts it queries my database for a group of objects that should be deleted because they're too old. And I have a for loop that I want to use to delete them. But when the for loop starts and I have a variable (in this case it should be called iterator right now) set to 0, `var iterator = 0` but it keeps getting set to the length of my array.

So when the for loop starts, instead of iterator being equal to 0, it's equal to 3. And then when the loop happens, it breaks because it tries to access `data[3].ChildID;` for an array of size 3, instead of `data[0].ChildID;`

What could be causing this?

```
app.listen(3000, function() {
console.log("Launch successful. To access app, open your browser and insert the following URL into your address bar: http://localhost:3000/");
// var i = 0;
// setInterval(updateDB.callUnenrolledList(function(err, data){
//     if(err) {
//       // do nothing
//     }
//     // send the data
//     console.log("Checking for Unenrolled Children...");
//     res.send(data);
//   }), 1000);

updateDB.callUnenrolledList(function(err, data){
    if(err) {
      // do nothing
    }
    console.log("Checking for Unenrolled Children...");
    if(data.length < 1){
      console.log("Database is up to date. No Children Deleted");
      //Do nothing. There are no unenrolled children
    } else {
      //Check to see if children have been "idle" for 5 years (arbitrary time set by SPCCC) and delete them if they have been
      var currentDate = new Date();
      var iterator = 0;
      for(iterator; iterator < data.length; iterator++);{
        console.log(iterator);
        // var unenrolledDate = new Date(data[i].unenrolledDate);
        var unenrolledDate = new Date("5/4/2017");
        var difference = currentDate - unenrolledDate;
        if(difference > 86400000){
          console.log("Over 1 day old. Delete child!");
          console.log(iterator);
          var child = data[a].ChildID;
          var ID = {ChildID: child};
          updateDB.deleteChildFromDatabasePermanently(ID);
          console.log("child deleted");
        } else{
          //do nothing
        }
        // if(difference > 157700000000){
        //   console.log("Over 5 years old. Delete child!");
        // }
      }
    }
  });
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a misplaced `;` at the end of your *for loop* line :)

Try changing this:

```
for(iterator; iterator < data.length; iterator++);{
```

to:

```
for(iterator; iterator < data.length; iterator++) {
```

That silly typo neatly explains `iterator` being equal to `data.length`, as you reported.

Comment: Happens to all of us :)... sometimes you just need a fresh pair of eyeballs.